# divisibility question in abstract algebra over a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

$d|n \Rightarrow x^{p^d} - x$ divides $x^{p^n} - x$ over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ where $\mathbb{F}$ is a field.

Attempt:

$d|n \Rightarrow x^{p^d} - x$ divides $x^{p^n} - x \Rightarrow x^{p^d - 1} - 1$ divides $x^{p^n - 1} - 1 \Rightarrow p^d - 1$ divides $p^n - 1$ since $p^n - 1 = (p^d)^{\frac{n}{d}}-1$.

How does this look?

Comment: Please don't delete your question after it's been answered.

Answer (score 2):

You assume the result as your first step, and after that it's not clear what your goal is.  But you've come across an important fact, which is that what you're trying to prove is related to the fact that $p^d-1$ divides $p^n-1$.

First, let's make sure that we can prove this fact from scratch.  Let's write $n=kd$.  Then why does $p^d-1$ divide $p^{kd}-1$?  Here's a hint: if $y=p^d$, is it true that $y-1$ divides $y^k-1$?

And in fact, once we know that $p^d-1$ divides $p^n-1$, we can use the same trick to finish the problem.  If $p^n-1 = m(p^d-1)$, and z = $x^{p^d-1}$, then $x^{p^d-1} -1 = z-1$ and $x^{p^n-1} -1 = z^m-1$.

Do you see how to finish from here?

Answer (score 0):

$$d\mid n\implies n= kd\;,\;\;\text{so}:$$

$$x^{p^n}-1=\left(x^{p^d}\right)^{p^{kd-d}}-1=\left(x^{p^d}-1\right)\left(\left(x^{p^d}\right)^{p^{kd-d}-1}+\left(x^{p^d}\right)^{p^{kd-d}-2}+\ldots+x^{p^d}+1\right)$$

Comment: A bit of a typo there on the second line after first equality, I'm afraid you have the wrong polynomial to begin with also

Comment: I can't remember many instances when typing something was *soooo* hard. Thanx and edited, @PatrickDaSilva

Comment: You need to work with $x^{p^n} - x$, not $x^{p^n} - 1$!

Comment: @Patrick, I addressed the OP's doubt about what he wrote immediately before his last line...;) . Also, if he already knows a little about the multiplicative group of finite fields then the above is enough.

Comment: I don't really understand how your answer gives us the result "in a straightforward manner". I think there is more to say to get $x^{p^d} - x | x^{p^n} - x$. I actually don't even understand how your answer gets us there.

Comment: I wonder where did you get the "straightforward manner" thing from the answer...? Anyway, of course there is more to say. Do you want to give the full answer? Be my guest. Oh, you already did. Good.

Comment: I wasn't trying to be rude! I just don't understand your answer.

Comment: We need to use $d\mid n\Rightarrow p^d-1\mid p^n-1$, not $d\mid n\Rightarrow p^d\mid p^n$ as this answer does, because as Patrick notes we're discussing $x^{p^\square}-x$ not $x^{p^\square}-1$.

Answer (score 0):

You can either drop to the integer case by doing (not exactly) what you did (notice how your first line is the actual result...), which is fine, but there are some other tricks! You can use induction on $k = n/d$ as follows : 
$$
x^{p^n} - x = x^{p^{kd}} - x = x^{p^{kd}} - x^{p^{(k-1)d}} + x^{p^{(k-1)d}} - x.
$$
By induction you only need to prove that $x^{p^d} - x$ divides $x^{p^{kd}} - x^{p^{(k-1)d}}$. Then 
$$
x^{p^{kd}} - x^{p^{(k-1)d}} = \left(x^{p^{(k-1)d}}\right)^p - \left(x^{p^{(k-2)d}}\right)^p = (x^{p^{(k-1)d}} - x^{p^{(k-2)d}}) f_1(x)
$$
using the identity 
$$
a^n - b^n = (a-b)\left( \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i b^{n-1-i} \right)
$$ 
(The sum here would correspond to $f_1(x)$.) You can see that the factor obtained has the same shape as the previous one except that $k$ is replaced by $k-1$, so you can keep going until $k$ becomes $1$ :
$$
x^{p^{kd}} - x^{p^{(k-1)d}} = \left(x^{p^{(k-1)d}} - x^{p^{(k-2)d}}\right)f_1(x) = \dots = (x^{p^d} - x)f_1(x) f_2(x) \dots f_{k-1}(x).
$$
More generally, you can show that if $(p(x),q(x))$ stands for the g.c.d. of those two polynomials (and/or integers), then
$$
(x^m - 1, x^n - 1) = x^{(m,n)} - 1.
$$
The proof is quick : if $m > n$, write $m = qn + r$. Then 
$$
x^m - 1 = x^m - x^{m-r} + x^{m-r} - x^{m-2r} + \dots x^{n+r} - x^r + x^r - 1 = \left( \sum_{j=1}^q x^{jn} - x^{(j-1)n} \right) + x^r - 1 
= (x^n - 1)\left( \sum_{j=1}^q x^{(j-1)n} - x^{(j-2)n} \right) + x^r-1.
$$
Therefore you can apply the Euclidean algorithm on $m$ and $n$. This gives you
$$
(x^{p^d} - x, x^{p^n} - x) = x (x^{p^d-1} - 1, x^{p^n-1} -1) = x (x^{(p^d-1,p^n-1)} - 1) = x^{(p^d-1,p^n-1) + 1} - x
$$
and so $x^{p^d} - x$ divides $x^{p^n} - x$ if and only if $(p^d-1,p^n-1) = p^d-1$, i.e. if and only if $p^d-1 | p^n -1$. There are many ways to prove that $p^d - 1 | p^n - 1$ if and only if $d | n$, which is a stronger statement than what you were trying to prove! The easiest way is probably to write $n = qd + r$ with $0 \le r < d$ and write
$$
p^n - 1 = p^n - p^r + p^r - 1 = p^r(p^qd - 1) + p^r - 1 = p^r (p^d-1)\left( \sum_{j=0}^{q-1} p^{qd} \right) + p^r - 1
$$
and since $r < d$, $p^d-1 | p^n-1$ if and only if $r=0$, i.e. if and only if $d | n$.

Hope that helps.